# adding subject in email in flex mobile application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

**Problem:** How to send email to some person(s) with Subject line on some event?

**Platform:** Flash Builder 4.6, Flex Mobile Application

I am using following code on button click but it do nothing.

```
var email:String = "mailto:asifdegr8@gmail.com";
                const mailURL:String = email; 
                var targetURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(mailURL); 
                navigateToURL(targetURL);
```

Also tell how can I check it on desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

var email:String = "mailto:asifdegr8@gmail.com?subject=YOUR_SUBJECT_HERE";